# How to display record only once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, **Message** and **Comment**

Message, 
`has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy`

Comment, 
`belongs_to :message`

I have a scope to display only replied messages:
`scope :replied, -> { where(replied: true) }`

```
<% @messages.replied.each do |message| %>
  message_id:<%= message.id %>
  <%= message.comments.last.content %>
<% end %>
```

If a `message` has several `comments`, it is displayed as many time as it has comments...
Maybe it's obvious but I am stuck.

**GOAL:**
I want to display the message and its last comment only once...

edit: 
message has `subject` , `content` as string and text, `replied` is a boolean
comment has `content`

Comment: what's in `@messages` ? Also, It's supposed to be `Message.replied.each ...`

Comment: message has `subject` ,  `content` as string and text, `replied` is a boolean

Comment: did you try this `Message.replied.each ...` ?

Comment: Of course :), btw, we have change plans and we don't need this feature anymore so, thanks for helping